# select rows which have set of values in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have following problem.

I have filter of users in my project, and I want Select from database only users which have in table inastrument all of instruments specified by $fm_instrument.

table user:

```
id_user   |  user_type   |
--------------------------
|    1    |      2       |
```

table instrument looks like this:

```
| id_user_instrument   |  id_user     | instrument_title |
----------------------------------------------------------
|            1         |      1       |        organ     |
|            2         |      1       |        flute     |
|            3         |      1       |        piano     |
```

EXAMPLE: filter returns $fm_instrument='flute,organ'

And I doing this:

```
if(isset($fm_instrument) && $fm_instrument != '')
{
$instrument_arr = explode(',',$fm_instrument);
$instrument_sql = '';
foreach ($instrument_arr as $i=>$val) // pro kazdy nastroj
{
    if($i != 0) {$instrument_sql.=" AND ";}
    $instrument_sql .= " (  instrument_title='".$val."' ) ";
}
$instrument_sql_part = " AND ($instrument_sql)";
}    

$user_sql ="SELECT * FROM `user` AS pu 
LEFT JOIN instrument AS i USING(`id_user`) WHERE user_type=2 $instrument_sql_part ";
```

But it doesn't work for more than one instrument.

I'm sure that there is easier solution with right mysql_query, but my knowledges of mysql are not so good.

Thank you for your patience with me.

Comment: Just writing the SQL - 

SELECT * FROM `user` AS pu 
LEFT JOIN instrument AS i ON(pu.id_user = i.id_user) WHERE user_type=2 AND instrument_title IN ("flute","organ")

Comment: @Joddy user results have to match **all** instruments and not some

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give this a try

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  users
WHERE
  user_type = 2
AND
  id_user IN 
    ( SELECT 
        id_user 
      FROM (
        SELECT 
          id_user, 
          GROUP_CONCAT( instrument_title ) instrument_titles
        FROM 
          instrument 
        WHERE 
          FIND_IN_SET( instrument_title, 'flute,organ' )
        GROUP BY 
          id_user ) tmp
      WHERE 
        LENGTH( instrument_titles ) = LENGTH( 'flute,organ' ) );
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b94b/11/0)

Comment: You probably want to have `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(...) > 0`

Comment: I thought FIND_IN_SET returns an integer indicating the position of the sought term.  I'm not too familiar with mysql: will it do automatic type conversion?

Comment: @AleksG `False := 0` and `True := not False`

Comment: @Sir Rufo Once again your solution works excelent. You are mysql Guru :) thanx a lot man.